# Auto layout constraints: view disappears in today widget

Tags: ios, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint, ios8-today-widget, today-extension

I ran into this weird issue today:

After a **clean install**, my layout looks okay; a simple view with a button in it:

[image: Clean install]

I am using xibs instead of a Storyboard (not my decision :(), and it's rather simple:

[image: Constraints]

However, the next time I pull down the notification centre, the view disappears:

[image: Error]

I have printed out recursiveDescription and _autolayoutTrace in both cases, but it appears to be the same:

After a clean install:

```
<UIView: 0x78ee8dc0; frame = (0 0; 272 0); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x78edeb20>>
   | <XXXNormalButton: 0x78ef5a70; baseClass = UIButton; frame = (0 15; 130 32); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x78ee9da0>>
   |    | <UIImageView: 0x78e83330; frame = (0 0; 130 32); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x78e9f220>>
   |    | <UIButtonLabel: 0x7a13d660; frame = (39.5 6; 51.5 20); text = 'Button'; alpha = 0; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; animations = { opacity=<CABasicAnimation: 0x78e752e0>; }; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x7a13c150>>


_UIHostedWindow:0x78ef0d30
|   UIView:0x7a1420d0
|   |   _NCWidgetViewControllerView:0x7a151390
|   |   |   UIView:0x7a13f3c0
|   |   |   |   UIView:0x78ea1190
|   |   |   |   |   •UIView:0x78ee8dc0
|   |   |   |   |   |   *XXXNormalButton:0x78ef5a70'Please activate...'
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   UIImageView:0x78e83330
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   UIButtonLabel:0x7a13d660'Button'
```

When the error occurs:

```
<UIView: 0x78e84d00; frame = (0 0; 272 0); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x78e804e0>>
   | <XXXNormalButton: 0x78e42eb0; baseClass = UIButton; frame = (0 15; 130 32); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x78e87ba0>>
   |    | <UIImageView: 0x78f5c140; frame = (0 0; 130 32); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x78f5b9d0>>
   |    | <UIButtonLabel: 0x78e97f60; frame = (39.5 6; 51.5 20); text = 'Button'; alpha = 0; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; animations = { opacity=<CABasicAnimation: 0x78f23d40>; }; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x78e87fb0>>


_UIHostedWindow:0x78f5fe50
|   UIView:0x78f5e2a0
|   |   _NCWidgetViewControllerView:0x78e68bc0
|   |   |   UIView:0x78e9b270
|   |   |   |   UIView:0x78e082b0
|   |   |   |   |   •UIView:0x78e84d00
|   |   |   |   |   |   *XXXNormalButton:0x78e42eb0'Please activate...'
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   UIImageView:0x78f5c140
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   UIButtonLabel:0x78e97f60'Button'
```

A notable detail: the frame of the view in both cases is (0 0; 272 0), so I'm not even sure it should be visible.

Some context: I'm loading the xib from code. If I load a different xib, the layout is correct, so I'm guessing that some constraints might be missing.

What I've tried: I tried defining an explicit top, height, and bottom constraint for my button, and in this case I've got a conflict between the following constraints:

```
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x79f6f350 V:[XXXDefaultButton:0x79f6ea80'Please activate...']-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x79f6f1c0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x79f6f380 V:|-(10)-[XXXDefaultButton:0x79f6ea80'Please activate...']   (Names: '|':UIView:0x79f6f1c0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x79e46440 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UIView:0x79f6f1c0(0)]>"
)
```

If I understand correctly, `'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UIView:0x79f6f1c0(0)` means, that the view would like to auto-size itself with zero height.

I don't understand why this is happening. Since I'm forced to use xibs, adding a height constraint is out of the question (I've set the height in the attributes inspector though). I am completely stuck, any help would be appreciated.